# Connecting to PCIe 3G modem as Serial device through COM port in Windows 8.1 on Dell E7440

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, modem, 3g, wwan

I have Windows 8.1 with a Dell 3g card 5570, which is actually a Sierra Wireless MC8805 HSPA+ mini PCIe modem. It works great in windows.

Now I need to be able to access it as a serial device through the appropriate COM port, which I can't figure out how to do. Even if I disconnect from the connection, I have a few problems;

1. I can't figure out what COM port the device is on (see screenshots)
2. How do I tell whether windows is powering the device off due to inactivity? Disabling this setting seems to stop the device from working properly in windows.
3. I can't get putty to connect to it; Connecting to COM1 or any other COM port through Putty yields no results, with ATZ and AT commands.

How do I make sure the modem is accessible through a COM port? (This is essential for the software I am using)

[image]
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it has a COM interface?

Comment: The software I was using (Campbell Scientific LoggerNet) briefly showed it as a COM port- I can't remember which number though, and it has since disappeared from that list.

Perhaps it does not have a COM port. How would I find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sierra Wireless MC8805 doesn't have a COM port.  Refer to [their specifications](http://www.sierrawireless.com/productsandservices/AirPrime_Wireless_Modules/Essential_Modules/~/media/Data%20Sheet/AirPrime_datasheets/Sierra_Wireless_AirPrime_MC_Series_Intelligent_Embedded_Modules.ashx) listed under "UART" interface.

[image]

Comment: Dang it. If I bought one of the modules that lists a UART (i.e. MC9090 or MC809x or MC5728V would I be able to access the COM port though the UART?

Comment: @Chris It would at least be possible.  It might depend on the particular driver/firmware being used.

Comment: It seems I'll struggle to get hold of those models. Your answer is correct and I'll accept it. Do you have any suggestions of Mini PCIe modems available that have an accessible COM port?

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with Sierra Wireless MC7710 (connecting it to Mikrotik Router). It not have physical UART, but driver give to OS 5 serial interfaces in Linux . But Windows 8.x use for Qualicomm modems special native mode QMI (Qualcomm MSM Interface), where all configuration done over driver API (or maybe over IP)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411383/how-to-send-qmi-api-request-to-the-device-like-sierra-wireless-card-by-c